# AngularJS Filters not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-filter

I get curly braces when using filters in latest Internet explorer (11) when there is other text around the binding, like

```
<span>something {{date | date:'yyyy'}}</span>
```

Also when I've elements around the binding, like

```
<span>something</span>{{date | date:'yyyy'}}</span>
```

Anyone knows how to prevent that?

Full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/nVv2mM4US2JakTm1tGlF?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in AngularJS when it was attempting to access `window.history.state`:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10367

Change the Angular version to v1.3.15 or higher - it was fixed in v1.3.15 (your plunker uses v1.3.13). It doesn't seem to be related to filters; at least not directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it appears as this is not the issue in my case (or not the only one): I still see curly braces in 1.3.15 now. Maybe it's some other library though that's causing troubles, but console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I tested your plunker with 1.3.15 in IE and it renders the year correctly

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort. Strange. I'll try to narrow down which library causes this (if any at all) all will open a new question with a fiddle. Will accept your answer though as it's right and might help someone else in the future. Thanks again!